# How to compare substrings and parse numbers from a C string

Tags: c, string

I'm new to low level programming and have been stuck with the following problem:

I get a string in the following format:

```
?cmd=ASET&<hour>&<minute>
```

where the hour and minute values always consist of 2 decimal numbers.
So an example of the string that can be received is:

```
"?cmd=ASET&08&30"
```

I am trying to write an if statement that recognizes that the string starts with "?cmd=ASET" and changes two global variables called minute and hour to the values in the String. I've been trying to do this with strtok(), but have not had any luck so far. So the global layout of my if statement would be:

```
if (String starts with "?cmd=ASET") {
   minute = value found in the string;
   hour = value found in the string;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please click the grey checkmark next to the answer that works for you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, where cmd is a char * or char [] type variable.  Note, `strncmp()` is safer than `strcmp()`. In general, in C programming, you want to use the variants of functions that limit the length, to avoid stack overflow attacks and other security risks. And since string to numeric functions can fail if given bad input it is better to use a form where you can check their status, which is why `atoi()` and `atol()` are not recommended. `sscanf()` allows status to be checked as does `strtol()` so they are both acceptable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main() 
{
   char *string = "?cmd=ASET&12&30";
   #define ASET_CMD "?cmd=ASET"
   int hour = 0, minute = 0;
   if (strncmp(string, ASET_CMD, strlen(ASET_CMD)) == 0) {
       if (sscanf(string + strlen(ASET_CMD), "&%d&%d", &hour, &minute) != 2)  {
          printf("Couldn't parse input string");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
   }
   printf("hour: %d, minute: %d\n", hour, minute);
   return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

$ cc -o prog prog.c
$ ./prog
hour: 12, minute: 30
```

Comment: Even if windows lets you get away with it. `main` is a function of type `int` and really should return a value to the shell. (e.g. `return 0;`) Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Should initialize `hour` and `minute`. There is also missing a curly bracket for the inner if.

Comment: Also should include `stdlib.h` to prevent undefined reference to `exit` on unicies.

Comment: @David - stdlib.h is included.  Forss - Added missing brace. David - fixed program success exit.

Comment: @Forss - Don't see a reason to initialize hour, minute since they won't be referenced if the conversion fails.

Comment: Since SO is a learning site for many, many newcomers. You want to try and drive home the point of always intializing all variables to prevent and inadvertent attempt of reading/dereferencing an uninitialized value and stumbling off into undefined behavior. That's the only reason. You are 100% correct in its application here.

Comment: @Forss - ok, as a best practice, I did it :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `sscanf()` is available for OP, consider:

```
unsigned hour, minute;
int n;
int cnt = sscanf(buffer, "?cmd=ASET&%2u&%2u%n", &hour, &minute, &n);
if (cnt == 2 && buffer[n] == 0) Success();
else Failure();
```

`cnt` will have the value of 2 if the prefix matches and 2 numbers where found.
The `n` detects if any addtional characters exist in the string.

Answer (score 0):

there is a function atoi() which returns integer from string. 
You can parse string like that

```
char string[16];
strcpy(string, "?cmd=ASET&08&30");
if (String starts with "?cmd=ASET") {
   hour = atoi(string+10);
   minute = atoi(string+13);
}
```

where +10 is position for hour and +13 for minute.
here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int hour, minute;
    char string[16];
    strcpy(string, "?cmd=ASET&08&30");

    /* Check if string contains ?cmd=ASET */
    if (strstr(string, "?cmd=ASET") != NULL) 
    {
        /* Parse minute and hour */
        hour = atoi(string+10);
        minute = atoi(string+13);

        /* Print output */
        printf("Minute: %02d \nHour: %02d\n", minute, hour);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's tacky to use numeric offsets for the hour and minute. Named constants would be better. Further, `atoi()` can fail. `strtol()` is considered a better and safer string to integer conversion function and its status can be checked.

Comment: Another issue is that with `strstr()`, the string you're looking for may be anywhere in the string, so if there's garbage in the front, which might flag to a substantial error somewhere else in the code, or input, perhaps, your code would miss it. That's why strncmp() is a better choice given the input syntax described in the question.